# Remove Redo actions in Memento?

Tags: catel, memento

In my application a user can add rows to a DataGrid and change properties of each row. The user can also delete rows. It works fine to undo and redo these actions but if the user adds rows, say three, modify some values and then undo back to where there is only one row and then add a new row it seems illogical to be able to redo the undos(having new rows appear after the last added one). Thus when the user adds a new row I want to delete all Redos.

I tried to use RedoBatches to get an enumeration of all redos and then do Clear on each to remove them but the Redo button is still active and will Redo these actions when pressed.

Is this the proper way to try to achieve this or is it not possible or should I do it differently?

Answer (score 0):

When adding items using an object, you can use *UnregisterObject* to unregister. It will automatically remove empty batches as well.

Another hack is to cast the Undo / Redo batches properties to a List<> and modify them accordingly (but note that you are "messing" with internals in that case).

Comment: Which object should I unregister? The user adds row 1, 2 and 3, then undo the addition of row 3 and then add a new row. Redo will add a forth row. But if I instead unregister the object that holds the rows I will loose that redo (as wanted) but I will also loose all undos(the addition of the new row and row 2 and 1) and those I still want to keep. So the only option I have is to start "messing" with the internals, right?

Comment: Or create a PR that allows to clear empty batches. I think that's fairly easy.

Comment: Do not understand how that will help me remove existing Redos. Or have I totally misunderstood the Memento internals? As I have understood it, Memento has an Undo and Redo queue for each object it monitors and actions are moved between these to queues.

Comment: What I mean is: you can remove the items from the batch, but the batch itself would still be in the list. What you can do is a public method ClearEmptyBatches (or Cleanup, or whatever) which will clear all batches without actions.